# Dynamically condition execution XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two if condition in XSLT as shown below:

```
 <xsl:if test="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:SemiVehicle>// for semi vehicle
 //code to show values from XML(ie 20,20)
</xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:NonsemiVehicle>// for non-semivehicle
 //code to show values from XML(ie 10,10)
</xsl:if>
```

My XML is as follows:

```
// For Non semi vehicle
<RoutePart Id="374941">
<Vehicles>
<NonsemiVehicle>
<OverallLengthListPosition xmlns="http://www.esdal.com/schemas/core/vehicle">
              <OverallLength>
                <IncludingProjections>10</IncludingProjections>
                <ExcludingProjections>10</ExcludingProjections>
              </OverallLength>
            </OverallLengthListPosition>
</NonsemiVehicle>
</Vehicles>
</RoutePart>

// For Semi vehicle
<RoutePart Id="374941">
<Vehicles>
<SemiVehicle>
<OverallLengthListPosition xmlns="http://www.esdal.com/schemas/core/vehicle">
              <OverallLength>
                <IncludingProjections>20</IncludingProjections>
                <ExcludingProjections>20</ExcludingProjections>
              </OverallLength>
             </OverallLengthListPosition>
</SemiVehicle>
</Vehicles>
</RoutePart>
```

When I parse this XSLT every time SemiVehicle is listed first and nonsemi vehicle as second. I want this dynamically as per my given XML every time.

Help me, please.

Edited XSLT details :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="http://test/schemas/core/proposedroute"
    xmlns:ns2="http://test/schemas/core/movement"
    xmlns:ns3="http://test/schemas/core/vehicle"
    xmlns:ns4="http://test/schemas/core/commontypes"
    xmlns:ns5="http://test/schemas/core/route"
    xmlns:ns6="http://test/schemas/core/drivinginstruction"
    xmlns:ns7="http://test/schemas/core/formattedtext"
    xmlns:ns8="http://test/people/bs7666"
    xmlns:ns9="http://test/schemas/core/annotation"
    xmlns:ns10="http://test/schemas/core/caution"
    xmlns:ns11="http://test/schemas/common/movementversion"
    xmlns:ns12="http://test/schemas/core/contact">

  <xsl:param name="Contact_ID"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="UnitType"></xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="DocType"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/ns1:Proposal">

    <html>
      <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">

        <br/>
        <b>Provisional Route</b>



        <!--Change Code Start RM#4604 21 july-->
        <xsl:variable name="FirstVehicle">

          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles">
            <xsl:if test="ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary != ''">
              <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary, '##**##')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary,'##**##')"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="StatusVehicle">
          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles">
            <xsl:if test="ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary != ''">

              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary, '##**##')">

                  <xsl:if test="$FirstVehicle != substring-after(ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary,'##**##')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
                  </xsl:if>

                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:if test="$FirstVehicle != ns3:ConfigurationSummaryListPosition/ns3:ConfigurationSummary">
                    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="CountVehicles">
          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart">

            <xsl:if test="$UnitType=692001">
              <xsl:if test="$StatusVehicle = 'false'">
                <item>
                  Leg:
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(ns2:Name, '##**##')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns2:Name, '##**##')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:Name" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <!--Changes for RM#4998-->
                    <xsl:when test="contains(ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Metric/ns2:Distance, '##**##')">
                      <xsl:call-template name="SplitAlternative">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after(ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Metric/ns2:Distance, '##**##')"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select=" OR"></xsl:with-param>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:call-template name="SplitAlternative">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Metric/ns2:Distance"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select=" OR"></xsl:with-param>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </item>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$UnitType=692002">
              <xsl:if test="$StatusVehicle = 'false'">
                <item>
                  Leg:
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(ns2:Name, '##**##')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns2:Name, '##**##')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:Name" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <!--Changes for RM#4998-->
                    <xsl:when test="contains(ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Metric/ns2:Distance, '##**##')">
                      <xsl:call-template name="SplitAlternative">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after(ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Imperial/ns2:Distance, '##**##')"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select=" OR"></xsl:with-param>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:call-template name="SplitAlternative">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Distance/ns2:Imperial/ns2:Distance"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select=" OR"></xsl:with-param>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </item>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="VehiclesArray" select="msxsl:node-set($CountVehicles)/item" />

        <!--Change Code End RM#4604 21 july-->



        <!--For Semi Vehicles-->
        <xsl:if test="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:VehicleSummaryListPosition/ns3:VehicleSummary/ns3:Configuration/ns3:SemiVehicle/ns3:Summary !=''">
          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:VehicleSummaryListPosition/ns3:VehicleSummary/ns3:Configuration/ns3:SemiVehicle">

            <xsl:variable name="getPosition" select="position()" />

            <xsl:if test="$getPosition &gt; 1">
              <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="$VehiclesArray[$getPosition]"/>
              </b>
              <br></br>
            </xsl:if>
            <br/>
            <table style ="margin-left" border = "1">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b>
                    <!--TODO 1-->
                    Semi trailer
                  </b>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <b>
                    <xsl:if test="ns3:Summary!='' ">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Summary"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </b>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!--</xsl:if >-->
              <xsl:if test="ns3:GrossWeight/ns3:Weight!=''">
                <tr>
                  <td>Gross weight:</td>

                  <td colspan="2">
                    <xsl:if test="ns3:GrossWeight/ns3:Weight!=''">
                      <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:GrossWeight/ns3:Weight, '##**##')">
                          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:GrossWeight/ns3:Weight, '##**##')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:value-of select="ns3:GrossWeight/ns3:Weight"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>

                      <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$UnitType='' or $UnitType=692001">
                          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>kg
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>kg
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </td>


                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="ns3:AxleConfiguration/ns3:AxleWeightListPosition/ns3:AxleWeight !=''">
                <tr>
                  <td>Axle weight:</td>

                  <td colspan="2">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns3:AxleConfiguration/ns3:AxleWeightListPosition">

                      <xsl:if test="ns3:AxleWeight!='' and ns3:AxleWeight/@AxleCount!=''">
                        <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:AxleWeight, '##**##')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:AxleWeight, '##**##')"/>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns3:AxleWeight"/>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>kg<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text> x<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
                        <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:AxleWeight/@AxleCount, '##**##')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:AxleWeight/@AxleCount, '##**##')"/>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns3:AxleWeight/@AxleCount"/>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:if>

                      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        ,
                      </xsl:if>

                    </xsl:for-each>

                  </td>


                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
            </table>
            <br/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--For Semi Vehicles Ends here-->

        <!--For Non Semi Vehicles-->
        <xsl:if test="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:VehicleSummaryListPosition/ns3:VehicleSummary/ns3:Configuration/ns3:NonSemiVehicle/ns3:ComponentListPosition/ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Summary != '' 
                  or ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:VehicleSummaryListPosition/ns3:VehicleSummary/ns3:Configuration/ns3:NonSemiVehicle/ns3:ComponentListPosition/ns3:Component/ns3:LoadBearing/ns3:Summary != '' ">

          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:RouteParts/ns2:RoutePartListPosition/ns2:RoutePart/ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:VehicleSummaryListPosition/ns3:VehicleSummary/ns3:Configuration/ns3:NonSemiVehicle/ns3:ComponentListPosition">

            <xsl:variable name="getPosition" select="position()" />

            <xsl:if test="$getPosition &gt; 1">
              <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="$VehiclesArray[$getPosition]"/>
              </b>
              <br></br>
            </xsl:if>

            <br></br>
            <table style ="margin-left" border = "1">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b>
                    <!--TODO 1-->

                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:Component, 'tractor')">
                        Tractor
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:Component, 'trailer')">
                        Trailer
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(ns3:Component, 'spmt')">
                        SPMT
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        Tractor
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </b>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <b>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Summary, '##**##')=false()">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Summary"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="contains(ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Summary, '##**##')=true()">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Summary, '##**##')"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="contains(ns3:Component/ns3:LoadBearing/ns3:Summary, '##**##')=false()">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns3:Component/ns3:LoadBearing/ns3:Summary"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="contains(ns3:Component/ns3:LoadBearing/ns3:Summary, '##**##')=true()">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns3:Component/ns3:LoadBearing/ns3:Summary, '##**##')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </b>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!--</xsl:if >-->
              <xsl:if test="ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Weight!=''">
                <tr>
                  <td>Gross weight:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">

                    <xsl:call-template name="parseString">
                      <xsl:with-param name="list" select="ns3:Component/ns3:DrawbarTractor/ns3:Weight"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="$UnitType='' or $UnitType=692001">
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>kg
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>kg
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
            </table>
            <br/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--For Non Semi Vehicles Ends here-->

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Changes for RM#4998 start-->
  <xsl:template match="text()" name="SplitAlternative">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="' OR'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCounter" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
      <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,' OR'), ' OR')"/>
      <!--<xsl:value-of select="$vToken"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;,&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pCounter"/>-->

      <xsl:if test="not($pCounter = 1)">
        or<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$UnitType='' or $UnitType=692001">
        <xsl:variable name="varKM" select="round(number($vToken) div number(1000))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$varKM"/> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>km
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$UnitType=692002">
        <xsl:variable name="varMiles" select="round(number($vToken) div number(1760))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$varMiles"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>miles
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:call-template name="SplitAlternative">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
      "substring-after($pText,'OR')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pCounter"
        select="$pCounter + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show a complete (and minimal) XSLT stylesheet and also clearly show what the output should be, for each of those input XML documents. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: XSLT is very large and output will not make any difference to this, I just want a dynamic order of IF condition. Let me know if more clarification is required. Many Thanks.

Comment: I _already_ let you know that more clarification is required. That your XSLT stylesheet is very large partly _is_ the problem. Break it down and isolate your issue in a very small stylesheet and post it here.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Hi Please see details in question under heading "Edited XSLT details"

Comment: @MathiasMüller Can you help me ?

Comment: I can only repeat myself: your XSLT stylesheet is too large, both for SO and for yourself. Find the part that causes problems and _isolate_ it in a separate stylesheet. _"also clearly show what the output should be, for each of those input XML documents."_. There are also two answers already that you can read and react to.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need those conditional checks? If you simply use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to process all child elements of `Vehicles` or if there are some you don't want to process you can of course also use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:SemiVehicle | ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:NonsemiVehicle"/>
</xsl:template>
```

plus a template (or more) for outputting the values you want to output then the elements are processed and output in document order.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:SemiVehicle
```

is true if there is at least one SemiVehicle found, and the condition

```
ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/ns3:NonsemiVehicle
```

is true if there is at least one NonsemiVehicle found.

So usually both conditions will be true and both branches will be executed. I suspect that's not what you want. I suspect you want to process all the vehicles, with different logic for SemiVehicles and NonsemiVehicles.

That's what template rules are for. I think your code should look something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ns2:RoadPart/ns2:Vehicles/*"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:template match="ns3:SemiVehicle">
  //code to show values from XML(ie 20,20)
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns3:NonsemiVehicle">
  //code to show values from XML(ie 10,10)
</xsl:template>
```

except that the structure for both kinds of vehicle seems to be so similar that you might want to use the same template rule for both.